# Alternative to the "Purge" command?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, memory-management

For anyone unfamiliar with the `Purge` command, it cleans out inactive memory.  I guess it's included with the dev tools.  I assumed that's how other apps like `iFreeMem`, `iMemoryCleaner`, `iCleanMemory` and others do it.  However, the purge command won't work if the dev tools aren't present.

Any alternatives that work the same way without the dev tools installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's never any reason to run the `purge` command unless you're a developer. It will only ever **decrease** system performance (by purging cached data, requiring the system to reload data from the hard disk).

That being said, you can take a look at how `purge` works with the `otool -tV` command. It appears to use an undocumented function called `CPOSXPurgeAllDiskBuffers()`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for finding that.  How do I use it, though?  Running it as a function seems to cause a linker error during build.

Comment: No idea. You'll have to do the reverse engineering yourself.

Comment: I am a developer and purge is not working anymore on Lion, after the last upgrade. At least not for me. So, the question stands... do you know any alternative for purge? thanks.

Comment: Seems to work for me. It can take some time to do its thing, though!